# Using AppleScript to clean up Address Book behaves weirdly when it comes to social profiles

Tags: applescript, addressbook, duplicates

I have been successfully writing and updating an AppleScript to remove duplicate email addresses as well as duplicate URLs from Address Book contacts.

With all social networking and sync software / services, contacts are getting populated with social network URLs and more recently Apple added social profiles to its Address Book scripting dictionary

While I have managed to deal with duplicate emails, URLs, and even with matching social network URLs with social profiles (and remove them), I am blocked in my last step : identify duplicate social profiles and remove them

While I can successfully identify a duplicate social profile, I haven't found the syntax to remove it from a contact, like what can easily be done with duplicate email addresses

```
    repeat with email_id in duplicate_emails
        delete (emails of this_person whose id is email_id)
    end repeat
```

here is the error message I get when executing

```
        delete (every social profile where id is socialProfile_id) in this_person
```

or

```
        delete (social profiles of this_person whose id is socialProfile_id)
```

or

```
        delete (every social profile whose id is socialProfile_id) in this_person
```

> error "Erreur dans Address Book : Le gestionnaire AppleEvent a échoué." number -10000

Any clues ? Source code available upon request

-- P

Answer (score 2):

I think this might work... the problem is that social profile is not linked to the contact info like emails, phonenumbers... maybe it will work after an OS Update, maybe it already work s on OSX 10.8 ;-)

```
--© hubionmac.com 21.03.2012
-- example code that REMOVES ALL SOCIAL PROFILES
-- from every selected person in your Address Book
-- de-facebook, de-twitter,… you contacts ;-)

set mySelectedPersons to selection

repeat with aSelectedPerson in mySelectedPersons
  set social_ids to id of (every social profile of aSelectedPerson)
  repeat with social_id in social_ids
    my delete_social_profile(aSelectedPerson, social_id)
    save
  end repeat
end repeat

on delete_social_profile(thePerson, theID)
  --handler for removing social profiles from Address Book
  --only way since social profile is not contained by contact info or something else and so delete social profile xy does not work
  -- input a single reference to a person in the address book and
  -- a the uniq ID of a social profile as text
  tell application "Address Book"
    set social_index to 0
    repeat with i from 1 to (count of every social profile of thePerson)
      if (id of social profile i of thePerson) as text = theID as text then
        set social_index to i
        exit repeat
      end if
    end repeat
    if social_index = 0 then error "error on delete_social_profile, given ID was not found in this person"
    --you cannot delete/kill a social profile, but when you remove/take away
    --all stored information (username and URL) from it, it commits suicide
    --and is removed from the address book, philosophic programming, isn't it?
    set user name of social profile social_index of thePerson to ""
    set url of social profile social_index of thePerson to ""
  end tell
end delete_social_profile
```

Comment: This hack is still needed in 2023.